# Change the Row a Filter Appears In

Tags: excel, vba

Currently I have a macro set up where the filter arrows will appear on row 2.  However I want the filter arrows to appear on row 3 instead.  One of my issues is someone else did this macro so I am having a hard time figuring out where I need to edit to make this happen.

This is what I have in VBA for the macro

```
Sub VG_vendor()
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    'Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim VersionName As Range
    
    Dim Response

'Unfilter Ad Model before generating vendor guide
ActiveSheet.Range("A:EM").AutoFilter Field:=2

Response = MsgBox("WARNING! ADVERTENCIA! ACHTUNG! Columns will be deleted, did you save?", vbYesNo)
 If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
 
  Columns("A:CE").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    
Rows.Hidden = False

With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    End With

    
    'create source range

    Set Source = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Range("A1:de2000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set VersionName = Range("b8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    

    If Source Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The source is not a range or the sheet is protected, please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'create temp file

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    

    'copy source range to temp file
    
    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With
    
    'Delete non vg columns
    
 

Range("E:F").Delete
Range("F:F").Delete
Range("G:K").Delete
Range("H:AR").Delete
Range("R:BK").Delete
    
    Range("C1:H8").ClearContents
    Range("C1:H8").ClearFormats
    

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    'TempFileName = "VG" & " " & VersionName
    
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.25)
    .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
    .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
    .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.2)
    .Orientation = xlLandscape
    .PaperSize = xlPaperLetter
    .Zoom = 60
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
    End With
    
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9").Value = "AD RETAIL"

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D:DE").FormatConditions.Delete

Range("2:7").Delete
    
    '(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
    

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 97-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2016
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If
    
    Call Delete_with_Autofilter_Array
    
    Call Delete_with_Autofilter_SunCity
    
    Call DeleteEmptyRows
    
    Call VG_Setup

'    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 '   Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

  '  With Dest
'       .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
 '       On Error Resume Next
  '      With OutMail
   '         .To = "Sun City"
    '        .CC = ""
     '       .BCC = ""
      '      .Subject = "Vendor" & " " & VersionName & " " & "Ad Sheet"
       '     .Body = "Hello, the" & " " & VersionName & " " & "ad sheet is attached, thank you."
        '    .Attachments.Add Dest.FullName
            
         '   .Display
            
       ' End With
        'On Error GoTo 0
        '.Close savechanges:=False
    'End With

    'Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    'Set OutMail = Nothing
    'Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    End With
    
'Call RowKiller
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A3:EM" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter Field:=2`